# Can I integrate an app with the iPhone message app?

Tags: iphone, ios5

Is it possible to integrate with the Message app (Apple core app)

E.g. if a user type a series of characters could an app intercept these keys and present an option window or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No- it's not possible to capture entered text from the iOS Messages app.  The App Sandbox prevents this.